# Write some part of a bson file into another bson file in java

Tags: java, file, bson

I have a bson file,(a.bson). I want to read this file and extract some part of it and then save these parts into another BSON file (b.bson).
Currently, I can read my source file (a.bson) using org.bson.BSONEncoder and extract my favorite parts of it (e.g., key1 and key2 for each row of source fila). Now I want to save these data in another bson file (b.bson). In fact, I need to save this data in a bson file because this file has structure a I can easily check rows have contains spacial value or not. I write this code and

```
import org.bson.BSONEncoder;
public static void createmyFile(File sourceFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    BSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();                        

    try {
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            BSONObject bsonSingleRow = decoder.readObject(inputStream);  
          // --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
         // Write bsonSingleRow.get(key1) & bsonSingleRow.get(key2) into new file
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }        
}
```

Please help me to complete above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you want 2% (select randomly) data from source file

```
File file = new File("a.bson");
        String path = "b.bson";
        BasicBSONEncoder encoder =  new BasicBSONEncoder();
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        BSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();  
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                BSONObject bsonSingleRow = decoder.readObject(inputStream);                
                c = bsonSingleRow.get("yourKey").toString();
                    if (Math.random()> .98))
                    Files.write(Paths.get(path), encoder.encode(bsonSingleRow),StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);                        
                }                                                
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
```